# Does one need to file one's nails in the same order used when cutting one's nails?

Tags: parts-of-the-body, nail-cutting

See [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71158/5275)  related to the order for cutting one's nails.

Does one need to follow this same order when one files or paints (manicures) the nails, or does it only apply to cutting?

The SHulchan Aruch that discusses the concept of having an order for cutting nails is written with regard to cutting nails for Shabbat and Yom Tov. I understand that this is related to beautifying one's body / appearance. If that's so, then filing / manicuring one's nails seems to fall in the same category / reasoning.

Comment: Not sure but may be that these precautions are for making difference with the toilet of death person before kevura. So if it is true, it is not relevant for painting

Comment: @kouty What is "toilet of death person "?

Comment: I think @kouty meant: I'm not sure, but it may be that these precautions are for distinguishing one's own toilet from the preparation of a corpse for burial. If that's true, then the precaution would not apply to painting.

Comment: @msh210 I am clueless. What does a toilet prep. have to do with anything, here?

Comment: @DanF http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toilet

Comment: @DanF I'm guessing kouty is French and toilet means washing.

Comment: @msh210 Sorry ... still clueless. What are we "preparing" & what does the dead have to with the toilet and nail filing?

Comment: DanF, we prepare bodies for burial. I don't know much about it, but @kouty apparently says that this includes cutting nails (not in the order we use on live people).

Comment: For the record I asked about filing to a Rosh Yeshiva of mine who liked to dabble in Kabballa on the side. He said he had no real idea but would guess filing would get the skipping procedure as well. If I ever get around to writing up an answer to your other nail cutting question, you will probably be able to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[Ashel Avraham (Butshash) 2nd Edition 260 "Odot"](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14125&st=&pgnum=97&hilite=) writes that the halachot of cutting nails does not apply to filing nails. This should apply to cutting them in a specific order as well.